# Can't find big file that's preventig git push

Tags: r, git, github

So I made a little error and at some point committed a big file called `.RData` that is 108 mb in size.
I, kind of panically, then did a `git rm --cached .RData`.
However, I still cannot push the commits to my remote.
After the `git push`, I always get this message:

```
remote: error: Trace: 7c9c0060d88b48827d9e9904b1934066d6c1246b93268a4344e430c0603181fe
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File .RData is 108.33 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

However, I don't know where to look for this `.RData`-file. Its certainly not in the directory and when I do a `git rm --cached`, I get:

```
fatal: pathspec '.RData' did not match any files
```

Maybe someone has an idea how I could get rid of this file.

Comment: Might be in a previous revision, not necessarily at the tip of the branch you are trying to push.

Comment: Thanks:)! any advice how I could find and delete it?